# What logic error do I have in this SQL check constraint?

Tags: sql-server, check-constraint

I spent hours last night trying to figure out what's wrong with the check constraint below. I want to enforce the following rule:

- Either all rows are null
- Or Col1 is not null and only one of the other columns is not null (if col4 is set, it should be set to true)

I'm able to insert rows with only Col1 set, but I want an error thrown instead.

```
    create table TestTable
    (
        Col1 varchar(10) null,
        Col2 varchar(10) null,
        Col3 varchar(10) null,
        Col4 bit null,
    )


    alter table TestTable add constraint X check
    (
        (Col1 is null and Col2 is null and Col3 is null and Col4 is null) or
        (
            Col1 is not null and
            (
                (Col2 is not null and Col3 is null and Col4 is null) or
                (Col2 is null and Col3 is not null and Col4 is null) or
                (Col2 is null and Col3 is null and Col4 = 1)
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: It works for me. Check this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35bfc/1)

Comment: Should this `insert testtable values ('a',null,null,null)` work or not?

Comment: @thepirat000, sorry, i edited my code. The issue must be with Col4 set to 1 though I don't quite understand why

Comment: What's the purpose of comparing Col4 to _1_ when you said that the constraint is all about _NULLS_ and _NOT NULLS_

Comment: sorry, i forgot to update the second bullet point. see the edit.

Comment: Just add `and Col4 Is Not Null` to the last condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality comparison doesn't work with NULLs:

```
alter table TestTable add constraint X check
(
    (Col1 is null and Col2 is null and Col3 is null and Col4 is null) or
    (
        Col1 is not null and
        (
            (Col2 is not null and Col3 is null and Col4 is null) or
            (Col2 is null and Col3 is not null and Col4 is null) or
            (Col2 is null and Col3 is null and (Col4 is not null and Col4 = 1))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Ok, this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks! But, shouldn't Col4 = 1 automatically imply Col4 is not null?

Comment: No. When Col4 is null, it's neither equal nor not equal to 1.